# Linear Approximations

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, derivatives

[image]

Can't figure out where I'm going wrong here. Isn't it just f(x)+f`(x) dx?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method

Comment: $f(x)+\Delta xf'(x)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $$27^{2\over 3}=9$$ The function is $$f(x)=x^{2\over 3}$$ which has derivative $$f'(x)={2\over 3}x^{-\frac{1}{3}}$$ and $$f'(27)={2\over 9}$$ Thus the approximation is $$9+0.07\times {2\over 9}=9.015555$$

Comment: That looks right, but 9.01555 still isn't giving me a correct answer, is there another way you could do it?

Answer (score 0):

An approximation of $f$ at $x + \Delta x$ is $f(x) + f'(x) \Delta x$. Pictorially, this is moving along line of slope $f'(x)$ from $f(x)$ a unit $\Delta x$ to get the approximate value of $f(x+\Delta x)$.

In this case, you want $f(x)=x^{1/3}$ and evaluate at $x=27,\Delta x = 0.07$.